# server can't find in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

Tags: dns, reverse, nslookup

I set up our custom DNS server in AWS and looks like doing nslookup a dns works fine in forward but if I do nslookup it in reverse like using its IP, it gives me an error as below

** server can't find x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

I can do nslookup any other public dns and IP back and forth but can't do nslookup a IP for some reason.

FYI, I used an internal IP to set this up.

Could you please give me any suggestions to resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: This is not programming related hence off topic here, but anyway, reverse records are not mandatory for all IPs so it just means the one you tested does not have one, which has no consequences most of the time.